# Electrons are Leptons. Other Leptons are muons, tauons and neutrinos but where are they found in the Atom?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, standard-model, leptons

We all know about Electrons and we use them every day.  WE SEE THEM in all the basic diagrams of ATOMS TOO - BUT where are the other LEPTONS?  Are they so short-lived that they really don't play a role in the universe?

Answer (score 1):

There are six leptons (and six corresponding anti-leptons): the electron, the muon, the tau, and three neutrinos called electron neutrinos, muon neutrinos, and tau neutrinos.

The muon has a lifetime of about two microseconds. The tau has a lifetime of about a third of a picosecond. They don’t play a role in normal atomic physics, although physicists sometimes experiment with, say, muonic hydrogen. Virtual muons and taus have tiny effects on, say, electrons.

Neutrinos can be emitted from atomic nuclei during radioactive decay.

There are trillions of solar neutrinos passing through our bodies every second, so they are a common part of our daily world without us realizing it. There are also neutrinos that are part of a “cosmic neutrino background” left over from the Big Bang and filling all of space.

Gluons are not leptons. They aren’t even fermions. They are “gauge bosons” and are to the strong force what photons are to electromagnetism.